WordPress site, long serve reponse times, how to debug this?
I'm currently working on optimizing a WordPress website, but I'm facing a persistent issue: the page load times are significantly delayed due to long server response times. I'm relatively new to WordPress, so I'm not very familiar with how to address this problem.

I've attempted to optimize the website using LiteSpeed Cache and have updated all the plugins, but the problem persists.

The backend server is Nginx, and the cache seemed to be working. I guess you were loading the page without serving from the cache? Just refresh it again and you should get a better page loading time.
curl -I https://cansultadev.wpengine.com/
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx
date: Wed, 14 Aug 2024 14:04:49 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 211142
vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-dns-prefetch-control: on
x-litespeed-tag: 7b5_HTTP.200,7b5_front,7b5_URL.6666cd76f96956469e7be39d750cc7d9,7b5_F,7b5_Po.1233,7b5_PGS,7b5_guest,7b5_,7b5_UCSS.a4862a9c4f0fe1dccf9c95e5844d6cfa,7b5_MIN.e85498dccfeea1fdadc0459a44e9e247.css,7b5_MIN.af8c24419b3ebf756ac421d1a54b0fe2.js
last-modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2024 20:30:25 GMT
link: <https://cansultadev.wpengine.com/>; rel=shortlink
x-litespeed-cache-control: public,max-age=604800
x-powered-by: WP Engine
vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
x-cacheable: YES:86400.000
cache-control: max-age=86400, must-revalidate
accept-ranges: bytes
x-cache: HIT: 9
x-cache-group: normal
x-orig-cache-control: max-age=86400, must-revalidate


To investigate the initial page loading slowly issue, you could use tool like Newrelic to observe the whole process loading time for PHP and DataBase, or simply ask WP Engine for the details.
I saw you have the LiteSpeed cache plugin installed. Since you have Nginx and other cache system running on the server already, the cache of LSCache part will auto-disable to avoid any conflict, so you may see the x-litespeed-tag without any hit or miss. You can still use the optimization features, e.g. CSS/JS optimization, Image Optimization, Guest Mode ..etc to improve the "page score".

i was looking into litespeed cache and since i am using quic.cloud i noticed this in my page optimazation  UCSS
https://ibb.co/WvMnGwY
can is it failing to optimiza the pages?

You can use QUIC Cloud, but the Cache part may still won't work due to the cache conflict. The UCSS optimization failure means the optimization does not pass through for some reason, a CSS code issue (unknown word) in your case. So your site will still use the original CSS and it won't cause the load issue. To check the CSS syntax issue, you can use this validation service https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
